# Access Key for a specific Blob / File Share

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I would like to configure Access Key(s) for a specific Blob or File Share inside a storage account.
Until now I had only found via UI and Docs ability to set Access Keys global to the entire storage account.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Shared Access Signatures for that which is the string that defines the access, policies of access, expiration time, etc. There is no way to do that using Access Key or something like else on the blob level.

[SAS overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/)

[How to do that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/)

Highly recommend to review [the Azure Storage security guidance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-security-guide/).